# Laravel routing hide path

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, routes, laravel-routing

I have a route like this

> http://localhost:8000/produk/slug-product

I want to my url like this, remove produk in url

> http://localhost:8000/slug-product

What should I do ?

Comment: change the route URI to not have the `produk` segment

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `.htaccess` to handle this. Define route for slugs without any segment at the end of the routes list in your app:

```
Route::get('{slug}', 'FrontController@getBySlug');
```

So, all requests which are not related to any of the routes, will go to the `getBySlug` method:

```
public function getBySlug($slug)
{
    $data = Model::findBySlug($slug);
    ....
}
```

Comment: the route cannot read, other URL route. it just read Route::get('{slug}', 'FrontController@getBySlug');.

example:

i have route like this 

Route::get('{category}', ['as' => 'category',   'uses' => 'Client\ProductController@category']);

Route::get('/login', ['as' => 'login',   'uses' => 'Client\ProductController@all_category']);

it just read 

Route::get('{category}', ['as' => 'category',   'uses' => 'Client\ProductController@category']);

Comment: Route::get('produk/{slug}', 'FrontController@getBySlug'), i want to remove produk in url

Comment: The above answer is correct. But place your 'slug' route at the end of your route file. Make it as the last route.